# Are there any libraries out there that can improve JavaScript execution performance?

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

I'm working on a project that will do some intensive computing (a social game that requires to do some real time image processing on the client side) on the web browser via JavaScript.

Everything worked well at first, but performance sucks when I tried to run it in an iOS UIWebView (WebView for android and Mobile safari worked fine). This is required for my project, since the web page needs to be displayed on some third party social sharing APP that will display my content in an UIWebView.

Later I found out that Apple actually disabled JIT in iOS UIWebView for security reasons (but I think it's for politics), which makes JavaScript execution performance a lot worse than in mobile Safari.

Currently my project is almost to an end, and the user experience in the iOS UIWebView is barely acceptable. ***So I thought without considering the help of JIT, is there any tool that can optimize my script for performance and not just for file size?*** Like doing stuff such as inline functions, precalculate and replace variables with literals, etc.

Comment: **Code review & optimization** seems the only option in such cases.

Comment: @RayonDabre writing my code directly optimized for execution will make my code a mess. The readability will be terrible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [WebWorker API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API):

> Web Workers provide a simple means for web content to run scripts in background threads. The worker thread can perform tasks without interfering with the user interface. In addition, they can perform I/O using XMLHttpRequest (although the responseXML and channel attributes are always null). Once created, a worker can send messages to the JavaScript code that created it by posting messages to an event handler specified by that code (and vice versa.) This article provides a detailed introduction to using web workers.

Code from: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/

```
var worker = new Worker('task.js');
worker.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
  console.log(e.data);
}, false);
worker.postMessage();
```

task.js

```
self.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
  self.postMessage(e.data);
}, false);
```

Comment: Well, I already reconstructed the program with Web Workers. There is some but not amazing performance boost in the UIWebView. More performance was gain to the browsers with JIT on. And now with 4 workers running in parallel, my iPhone gets quite hot after a few minutes.